# How to install php-xml on osx?

Tags: xml, macos, php

> Fatal error: Class 'DropDead\HomeBundle\Controller\DOMDocument' not found in ....

I need to install php-xml. I am using OS X. Cant find out how to install this extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure, you're doing it right? the dom extensions usually is compiled by default.

It looks like you run into namespacing issues. Try

```
$foo = new \DomDocument();
```

instead of just DomDocument() and it should hopefully run.

Comment: My stupid fault! You hero! Thank you.

Comment: Why does the \ fix it?

Comment: @BarryMode it's because of the namespace, instead of looking for the class in the current directory it's needs to look for it globally.